# Update $form based on $form_state

Tags: 7, forms

Shouldn't the form generating function get executed every time the form is rendered? Because I need to update some field suffixes based on the `$form_state` values and I don't know how to do this.

I have something like this:

```
function xxxx_some_form($form, &$form_state){
  $form["some_field"] = array(
    "#type" => "textfield",
    "#required" => true,
    // bla bla bla
  );
  drupal_set_message("whatever");
  $form["actions"]["do_action"] = array(
    "#type" => "submit",
    "#value" => t("Do action"),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

When I submit the form, the validation messages are displayed ( Eg: X field is required ) but the message from `drupal_set_message("whatever")` is not displayed.

Also, no other logic is executed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a form has a validation error, the form is rebuilt from cache, meaning that the form function isn't invoked.

I could move the `drupal_set_message` call over to a `#process` or `#preprocess` function on the form itself or on one of the methods. These should be called again.

If the form is displayed with `hook_menu` you could also make a callback function which calls `drupal_set_message` and then fetches the form. There are a lot of ways to get around this.

Comment: Thanks, never thought about a #process callback.  It seems promising but it looks like the `$form_state["values"]` is missing all `#type => 'value'` fields.

Comment: @MariusIlie `$form_state['values']` is not availble if the form has validation errors. This is by design and you should not use this outside submit handlers.

Comment: That's weird. All other fields have values in $form_state, just the fields of type `value` are missing. I guess I'll have to try something else then...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the form to be interactive?  Have you looked at the [#states](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states) ability of the form which lets you set up [conditional display](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7) of other fields, markdown elements, etc?

Field suffixes sounds like a very weird thing to modify on form submission, since the expectation with a submission is that the user is now done with the form.  And as for the messages, it is possible the template for the page you are working with [does not have the message print lines](https://www.drupal.org/node/184247).

Comment: Thanks but @googletorp's answer is closer to what I'm trying to achieve.